# Is there a way to update the value attribute of a textarea tag in real-time using an onchange event inside the same tag?

Tags: html, onchange

As I type inside the textarea tag I want the value to be updated.

```
<textarea onchange="some code" value=''></textarea>
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, e.g. `onchange="this.setAttribute('value', 42);"`. But I don’t see how this would be useful, and I wonder what problem you are trying to solve this way.

By HTML syntax, a `textarea` element cannot have a `value` attribute. By HTML5 drafts, and in browser practice, the `value` property of a DOM node corresponding to a `textarea` element reflects the content of the element.

Comment: Thanks. What is the '42' for?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. I'm trying to submit a form via ajax. The form has a textarea field (saved as 'comment' in my database) and nothing else. The textarea text that I enter is never stored in the database. However, if I hard-code the value attribute like this: `<textarea value="TEST"></textarea>, then it works. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @John Anderson:) Which technology are you using (Java, .NET, PHP)? and `<textarea value="TEST"></textarea>` doesn't work in all the versions of all the browsers. Although some versions of some browsers nowadays support it, HTML specifications indeed don't include the `value` attribute of `<textarea></textarea>`. Don't rely upon it even though it works.

Comment: @John Anderson, “42” is an example of a value. And the code works in the sense of doing exactly what you asked for in the question, changing the attribute value. You can see this e.g. by viewing generated HTML code in Firefox Web Developer Extensions. But this does not change the data submitted as part of form data, since that’s controlled by the content of the element; to change it, use `onchange="this.innerHTML = 42"` (though I still don’t know why you want to change the content to a specific value whenever the content is changed).

Comment: @John Anderson, your code probably just doesn’t store the text properly. Please post a complete example that demonstrates the issue. To begin with, if a `textarea` element lacks the `name` attribute, as in your example, it does not contribute to the form data upon normal form submission.